# Trigonometric Equations, Trouble solving.

Tags: trigonometry

$\displaystyle \sin x + \sqrt3\cos x =0$

$0< x <360^\circ$

Hey, I haven't done this question for a while and I forgot how to solve it. I have made attempts to solve it, such as splitting the sinx and cosx, but I still cant figure it out. Could some one please hint me or walk me through the steps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$\sin x+\sqrt 3\cos x=2(\sin x\times(1/2)+\cos x\times (\sqrt 3/2))=2\sin (x+60^\circ),$$
you'll have$$\sin x+\sqrt 3\cos x=0\iff \sin(x+60^\circ)=0.$$
Since
$$0\lt x\lt 360^\circ\iff 60^\circ \lt x+60^\circ\lt 420^\circ,$$
you'll have$$x+60^\circ=180^\circ, 360^\circ.$$
Hence, 
$$x=120^\circ, 300^\circ.$$

Comment: Clubbing $A\sin x+B\cos x=C$ is worth only if $C\ne0,$ right?

Comment: Well, I think this way can be used in the case $C=0.$

Comment: luckily here $\arccos \frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ is simple, else we had to deal with a little ugly trig inverse functions

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the point.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin x+\sqrt3\cos x=0\iff \sin x=-\sqrt3\cos x$$

$$\iff \tan x=-\sqrt3=-\tan60^\circ=\tan(-60^\circ)$$ as $\tan(-y)=-\tan y$

$$x=n180^\circ+(-60^\circ)$$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Haven't you omitted the case $\cos (x) = 0$?

Comment: @user18921, find my comment in your answer

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ denote a fixed but arbitrary element of $(0,2\pi)$.

Now the following are equivalent.

1. $\sin x + \sqrt{3} \cos x = 0$
2. $\sin x = -\sqrt{3} \cos x$
3. Either $\tan x = -\sqrt{3},$ or both $\cos x = 0$ and $\sin x = 0$

You can probably take it from here; please comment if you need a bit more help.

Comment: $\cos x=0\implies \sin x=?$ does it satisfy the given relation ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, you're right of course. I've edited.

Comment: you mean both $\cos x,\sin x$ are zero, then what will be fate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572585/fundamental-theorem-of-trigonometry ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, what do you mean?

Comment: if  both $\cos x,\sin x$ are zero, how $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ will hold ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, that's not how logic works! What matters is that if you plug an $x$ into line 2 and that same $x$ into line $3$, the resulting truthvalues will agree. Of course, we can simplify 3 by eliminating the vacuously false case, but there's no reason to completely solve the problem. Probably, the OP just needed help getting started.

Comment: I understood your point. I thought, it too obvious that both can not be zero :)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, haha yes, it looks kind of odd doesn't it? So be it.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x + \sqrt{3}\cos x =0$ can be written as $(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2i+(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})\sqrt{3}/2=0$. This simplifies to $e^{2ix}=(\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2)^2$. This is the same as $e^{2ix}=(e^{-\pi i/3})^2$ or $e^{2ix}=e^{-2\pi i/3}$, so $2x=-2\pi/3 + 2\pi k$, *i.e.*, $x=-\pi/3+\pi k$ for integral $k$.