# What trigonometric identities can prove this equation to be true?

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove this equation true with trigonometric identities?:
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)}-\tan(x) = \sec(x)$$

Comment: Try putting $\tan x$ and $\sec x$ in terms of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, then eliminate denominators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

You will have to use a little "trick" to simplify the fraction. Try multiplying the fraction by
$$\frac{1+\sin x}{1+\sin x}$$
which is the same as $1$, so it will preserve the value of the expression but alter its appearance just enough for you to figure out what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The only identity needed is
$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$.
The other information
is just definitions:
$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$
and
$\sec(x) = \frac1{\cos(x)}$.

First off,
I replace everything with
sin and cos,
and abbreviate them as "s" and "c".

$\frac{cos(x)}{1-sin(x)}-tan(x) = sec(x)$

becomes

$\frac{c}{1-s}-\frac{s}{c} = \frac1{c}
$.

I then clear fractions,
remembering that
$c \ne 1$ and $s \ne 0$.
This becomes

$c^2-s(1-s)=1-s
$

or
$c^2+s^2-s = 1-s$

Since $c^2+s^2 = 1$,
this is
$1-s = 1-s$
which,
as desired,
 is an identity.

If you want to do this
as a derivation,
just go through this
with just the left side
as a sequence of transformations.

You can even leave it
in fraction form:

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{c}{1-s}-\dfrac{s}{c}
&=\dfrac{c}{1-s}-\dfrac{s}{c}\\
&=\dfrac{c^2-s(1-s)}{c(1-s)}\\
&=\dfrac{c^2-s+s^2}{c(1-s)}\\
&=\dfrac{1-s}{c(1-s)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{c}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

You can write it down as:
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)}-\tan(x) = \sec(x)$$
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)}-\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}+\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)}=\frac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$
Changing its form
$$\implies (1+\sin x)(1-\sin x) = \cos x \cdot \cos x$$
$$\implies 1^2 - \sin^2x = \cos^2x$$
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x = 1$$
Which is correct, because it is [the Fundamental Theorem of Trigonometry.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572585/fundamental-theorem-of-trigonometry)

Answer (score 0):

**Another hint:**
It is equivalent to
$$\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\sin x}-\sin x=1$$
and it boils down to *Pythagoras' identity*.